# How can I save my TextView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, textview

I tried the edit my TextView by clicking. I did manage the edit but it cannot saved. When I close and re-open app or change activity its returning the default.

```
 textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    editText = new EditText(this);

    dialog.setTitle("Edit the text.");
    dialog.setView(editText);

    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            textView.setText(editText.getText());
        }
    });

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(textView.getText());
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio`. That tag is used for problems/questions about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Comment: Look at approaches to persistent storage: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextView` exists only on-screen. Once the `Activity` is closed, the data is gone.

If you want to store this persistently you will need to store the data in `SharedPreferences`, or in an SQLite database or in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Data will be gone after the App is cleared from the Ram.
There are following ways to store data in App

1. sharedPreference
2. Sqlite Database
3. Room Data Base

SharedPreference is one of the easiest way to save the data